# Button does not create JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am new in Java and am doing some window application for my college.
I am trying to do some kind of menu with three buttons in start, and when one of buttons is clicked it's supposed to create a JPanel with two more buttons, but my code doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;

public class mainScreen extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;

    public mainScreen() {
        super("Aplikacija za atletska natjecanja");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        final Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        setBounds(0, 0, screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBackground(SystemColor.info);
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.setBounds(200, 11, screenSize.width - 400, screenSize.height - (screenSize.height - 100));
        contentPane.add(top);

        JPanel mainMenu = new JPanel();
        mainMenu.setBounds(200, 110, screenSize.width - 400, screenSize.height - (screenSize.height - 30));
        contentPane.add(mainMenu);
        mainMenu.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        JButton btnTrkacke = new JButton("Trka\u010Dke");
        btnTrkacke.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
        mainMenu.add(btnTrkacke);
        btnTrkacke.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                JPanel panTrk = new JPanel();
                panTrk.setBounds(201, 140, (screenSize.width - 400) / 3, 30);
                contentPane.add(panTrk);
                panTrk.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

                    JButton btnTrkAtl = new JButton("Atleti\u010Dari");
                    btnTrkAtl.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
                    panTrk.add(btnTrkAtl);

                    JButton btnTrkDisc = new JButton("Discipline");
                    btnTrkDisc.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
                    panTrk.add(btnTrkDisc);
            }
        });

        JButton btnSkakacke = new JButton("Skaka\u010Dke");
        btnSkakacke.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
        mainMenu.add(btnSkakacke);

        JButton btnBacacke = new JButton("Baca\u010Dke");
        btnBacacke.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
        mainMenu.add(btnBacacke);
    }
}
```

That same panel should also be created when I click on the other two buttons, but on other the position... Is it better to create class for that pane and then call it when button is clicked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting to call revalidate and repaint on the contentPane after changing its components:

```
contentPane.revalidate();
contentPane.repaint();
```

e.g.,

```
     @Override
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JPanel panTrk = new JPanel();
        panTrk.setBounds(201, 140, (screenSize.width - 400) / 3, 30);
        contentPane.add(panTrk);
        panTrk.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        JButton btnTrkAtl = new JButton("Atleti\u010Dari");
        btnTrkAtl.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
        panTrk.add(btnTrkAtl);

        JButton btnTrkDisc = new JButton("Discipline");
        btnTrkDisc.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
        panTrk.add(btnTrkDisc);

        contentPane.revalidate();  // ***** added *****
        contentPane.repaint();     // ***** added *****
     }
```

- revalidate tells the container to re-lay out its components.
- repaint requests to the paint manager that the component and any children should be re-drawn.

As an aside: you're using null layout manager and absolute positioning with `setBounds(...)`, and you really don't want to do this. While to a newbie this seems the best way to create complex GUI's, the more you deal with Swing GUI creation, the more you will find that doing this will put your GUI in a straight-jacket, painting it in a very tight corner and making it very hard to extend or enhance. Just don't do this.

Comment: it works now tnx, and about that positioning, what is the best way to do complex GUI

Comment: @selomojemalo: the best answer is to study and learn the various layout managers that Swing and AWT have available, including using nested JPanels, each using its own layout manager and components.

Comment: i wos hoping for some specific answer :) but yes, that's what i have in mind :) tnx for answers

Answer (score 0):

will ask here, coz its same project

so it shuld work like this.... 3 buttons, and under each button is hiden panel with two button, so whan some button is clicked under him shuld show panel, whan some ather button is clicked under him shuld show panel, but ather two panels shuld hide.... and this works great until some button is clicked 2 time in a row, after that whan i click some ather button panel under that button dont wont to hide..

here is the code

```
JPanel mainMenu = new JPanel();
    mainMenu.setBounds(200, 110, screenSize.width - 400, screenSize.height - (screenSize.height - 30));
    contentPane.add(mainMenu);
    mainMenu.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

        JButton btnTrkacke = new JButton("Trka\u010Dke");
        btnTrkacke.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
        mainMenu.add(btnTrkacke);
        btnTrkacke.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                panTrk = new JPanel();
                panTrk.setBounds(201, 140, (screenSize.width - 400) / 3, 30);
                contentPane.add(panTrk);
                panTrk.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));   

                    JButton btnTrkAtl = new JButton("Atleti\u010Dari");
                    btnTrkAtl.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
                    panTrk.add(btnTrkAtl);

                    JButton btnTrkDisc = new JButton("Discipline");
                    btnTrkDisc.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
                    panTrk.add(btnTrkDisc);


                    contentPane.revalidate();
                    contentPane.repaint();
                    panSka.setVisible(false);   
                    panBac.setVisible(false);

            }
        });

        JButton btnSkakacke = new JButton("Skaka\u010Dke");
        btnSkakacke.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
        mainMenu.add(btnSkakacke);
        btnSkakacke.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                panSka = new JPanel();
                panSka.setBounds(201 + (screenSize.width - 400) / 3, 140, (screenSize.width - 400) / 3, 30);
                contentPane.add(panSka);
                panSka.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

                    JButton btnSkaAtl = new JButton("Atleti\u010Dari");
                    btnSkaAtl.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
                    panSka.add(btnSkaAtl);

                    JButton btnSkaDisc = new JButton("Discipline");
                    btnSkaDisc.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
                    panSka.add(btnSkaDisc);


                    contentPane.revalidate();
                    contentPane.repaint();
                    panTrk.setVisible(false);   
                    panBac.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        JButton btnBacacke = new JButton("Baca\u010Dke");
        btnBacacke.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
        mainMenu.add(btnBacacke);
        btnBacacke.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                panBac = new JPanel();
                panBac.setBounds(201 + (screenSize.width - 400) / 3 * 2, 140, (screenSize.width - 400) / 3, 30);
                contentPane.add(panBac);
                panBac.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0, 0, 0));

                    JButton btnBacAtl = new JButton("Atleti\u010Dari");
                    btnBacAtl.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
                    panBac.add(btnBacAtl);

                    JButton btnBacDisc = new JButton("Discipline");
                    btnBacDisc.setBackground(SystemColor.text);
                    panBac.add(btnBacDisc);



                    contentPane.revalidate();
                    contentPane.repaint();
                    panSka.setVisible(false);   
                    panTrk.setVisible(false);


            }
        });
```